# Compare two arrays keeping order in mind for one array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of build ids that are in order from the latest build (first element of the array is the latest). I want to compare it with another list that has a list of build ids as well but I want to see what is the latest build id (so go through the first list in order).

List1 has the build ids in order from the latest build (so list1[0] is the latest)

```
list1 = [009n1, 009d5, 006d4, 001s5, 008n3]
```

List2 has the build ids that have been executed.

```
list2 = [006d4, 001s5, 008n3, 006j1, 004k1]
```

So I want to compare the two lists and return the latest build that has been executed so when comparing `list1` and `list2`, I want it to return `006d4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the [intersection](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-26) of the arrays and grab the first element:

`(list1 & list2).first`

Comment: Although this is a nice and short solution, adding the important characteristics of the intersection would help. The fact that the order of `list1` is kept when the intersection is created is pretty important here.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["009n1", "009d5", "006d4", "001s5", "008n3"] 
list2 = ["006d4", "001s5", "008n3", "006j1", "004k1"] 

list1.find { |s| list2.include?(s) }
  #=> "006d4"
```

Of course, `Array#find` terminates as soon as it finds a match, so in the example `"001s5"`, `"008n3"` would not be examined.

If the arrays are large, and depending on the portion of build id's that have been executed, it may be faster to first convert `list2` to a set:

```
require 'set'

set2 = list2.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"006d4", "001s5", "008n3", "006j1", "004k1"}> 
list1.find { |s| set2.include?(s) }
  #=> "006d4"
```

Set lookups are very fast, comparable to hash key lookups, which is not surprising as sets are implemented with underlying hashes.